# Solr Error : ["undefined field query"]

Tags: solr, upgrade, sitecore-query

We have upgraded our Sitecore instance from **8** to **9.0.2** version. In one of our component on datasource level we are using query like below.

`query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Website']/Local Content/Header/Content Source`

On front-end everything is working as expected, but when I saw search logs I am seeing below error multiple times.

`ERROR Solr Error : ["undefined field query"] - Query attempted: [query:(.\/ancestor\-or\-self)]`.

If I am removing component from page then this error is not showing in search logs. Does anything needs to be updated in query syntax.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a known issue and you can find the solution here in this link.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002165

The root cause of this issue is that all queries that start from the query: or local: prefix lead to generating the query to Solr. However, a request to the index during resolving the data source for the SXA component must not be sent.

You can find this in this article.

For Sitecore `XP 9.0.2`, download and install the patch compatible with the affected  Sitecore XP and SXA product version found on this page:

https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.368851.373937/releases